# Value not saving into variable

Tags: php

I'm making a hangman game.

Everything works somewhat fine untill one last part.
I want to show the letters he managed to guess correctly.
This works somewhat but only after the 2nd guess.
But that's not the main problem i'm struggling with.

When a user actually guesses a correct letter it shows it in the secret word.
(secret word meaning the word the user has to guess but in dash lines)

But when the user guesses another time, the previous letter dissapears out of the secret word.

The last thing i'm struggling on is that when there are multiple letters in the same word the loops stop at the first one it finds.
(excuse me for my bad scripting. I'm fairly new to this thanks!)
(also excuse my Dutch)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hangman Back end php</title>
    <h1> Hangman </h1>
    <h3>Raad een letter van het te raden woord</h3>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$hang[0] =
' ------- 
 |/    | 
 |
 |
 |
 |
 | 
/|\
-------------';
$hang[1] =
' -------
 |/    | 
 |     o
 |
 |
 |
 | 
/|\
-------------';
$hang[2] =
' -------
 |/    | 
 |     o
 |     |
 |     |
 |
 | 
/|\
-------------';
$hang[3] =
' -------
 |/    | 
 |     o
 |     |
 |     |
 |    /
 | 
/|\
-------------';
$hang[4] =
' -------
 |/    | 
 |     o
 |     |
 |     |
 |    / \
 | 
/|\
-------------';
$hang[5] =
' -------
 |/    | 
 |     o
 |   --|
 |     |
 |    / \
 | 
/|\
-------------';
$hang[6] =
' -------
 |/    | 
 |     o
 |   --|--
 |     |
 |    / \
 | 
/|\
-------------';

function HasBeenUsed($allLettersGuessed, $letter){
    if ($allLettersGuessed =="") {
        #No letter guessed yet
        return false;
    }
    else {

        $hasLetter = false;
        #$length = strlen($allLettersGuessed);
        $hasLetter = strpos($allLettersGuessed, $letter) !== false;
            if ($hasLetter) {
                $hasLetter = true;
                return $hasLetter;
            }
            else {
                $hasLetter = false;
                return $hasLetter;
            }
        }
}
function Restart()
{

        $wrongGuess = 0;
        return array($oldLetterGuessed, $wrongGuess);
}
$solution = "DANSEN";
    if (isset($_GET['letterGuessed'])) {
        $currentGuess = $_GET['letterGuessed'];
        # Check the letter
        if (HasBeenUsed($solution, $currentGuess) == false) {
             echo "<b> Wrong </b>";
            $wrongGuess = $_GET['wrongGuess'] + 1;
             echo "<pre>" . $hang[$wrongGuess] . "</pre>";

        }
        else {
            $wrongGuess = $_GET['wrongGuess'];
            echo "<pre>" . $hang[$wrongGuess] . "</pre>";
        }
    }
    else {
        $wrongGuess = 0;
        $currentGuess = "";
    }
echo "<form name = 'myForm' method='get' action='hangman.php'>";

    # Alle geraden letters in een veriabele steken
    if (isset($_GET['oldLetterGuessed'])) {
        $oldLetterGuessed = $_GET ['oldLetterGuessed'];
        $allLettersGuessed = $oldLetterGuessed . $currentGuess;
        $allLettersGuessed;

        echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'oldLetterGuessed' value ='". $allLettersGuessed ."'>";
        echo $allLettersGuessed;
        echo "<p> The number of wrong guesses so far is $wrongGuess </p>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'oldLetterGuessed' value = '' >";
    }

echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'wrongGuess' value= '$wrongGuess'>";

if ($wrongGuess < 6) {
    $alphas = range('A', 'Z');
    # display letter buttons
    for ($i=0; $i < count($alphas) ; $i++) { 
        echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'letterGuessed' value = '" .  $alphas[$i] . "' >";
    }
}

else {
    #The Screen when you're lost
    echo nl2br("Oops looks like you've lost ");
    echo nl2br("\n");
    echo "The word you had to guess was ". $solution;
    echo nl2br("\n");
    echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'Restart()'>";
    echo "<input type = 'submit' value  = Restart'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
echo "</form>";
#Display omzetten naar lijnen
$display = $solution;
$length = strlen($display);
for ($i=0; $i < $length ; $i++) { 
    $display[$i] = "-";
}
if (isset($oldLetterGuessed)) {
    if ($oldLetterGuessed == "") {
        $display = "_ _ _ _ _ _";
    }
    else
    {
    $currentGuess = $_GET['letterGuessed'];
        # Looks at every letter and checks if it's the same
        if (HasBeenUsed($solution, $currentGuess) == true ) {
            # Positie zoeken $currentGuess in $solution
            $posLetter = strpos($solution, $currentGuess);
            # _ omzetten in de gegokte letter
            if ($posLetter !== NULL) {
                $display[$posLetter] = $currentGuess;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($display != $solution) {
        echo $display;
    }
    else {
        echo "You guessed the word";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sessions to store correct answers and their positions, here is an example based on your code:

Firstly start the session:

```
session_start();
```

Then you can store the correct guess and its position, this way:

```
$_SESSION['guessed'][$posLetter] = $currentGuess;
```

Above I create a session I called **guessed** to which I add the position and the current correct guessed letter.

Then when your page reloads it needs to display all correct guessed letters on their right position, so you need to loop on the session we created above :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['guessed'] )) { // Check if this session already exist
    foreach ($_SESSION['guessed'] as $position=>$guessed ) {
       $display[$position]=$guessed; // Assign the correct answer to the right position
    }
}
```

Also, I recommend you to use **post** method in your form instead of **get**, and for this kind of games better you use JavaScript so it's faster and the page doesn't have to reload on each guessed letter.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for taking time and helping me loads. I don't think i would've been able to solve it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

every time you are guessing a number there is a server call, and the previous guessed letter no longer exists!

so, what you need to do is use $_SESSION :)
i will demonstrate it here:

in your PHP code:

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[word]=array();

// if a letter is correct just push it to your session array:
array_push($_SESSION[word],$letter);

// then you iterate the session array and according to the letters that resides there
// you revile the correct letters
```